# Addons - Snippets as files

Tags: snippets

Is there a well-supported, 2.7.x+ compatible add-on to save Snippets as files like what we can do to templates in Expression Engine?

I think there are a lot of options out there but I just want something that is well supported and stable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My choose is Bjorn [SnippetsSync](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snippetssync) - simple and stable

Comment: +1 from me. Not quite a sync as template files work as EE still gets the data from the DB. But SnippetsSync does auto sync that part. Has worked well for me.

Comment: The only dev license I've purchased as a freelancer; +1

Comment: I tried using this but I get some weird things on snippets where I am using CE-Image. What is the parse order of this add-on?

Comment: @Nick Benson SnippetsSync and Snippet Sync are different addon-ons. The latter is the one that is not free.

Comment: @arvinsim it is used sessions_start session, so it must execute before any plugins. What weird things you have?

Comment: @MaxLazar Already solved it. The problem is not related to parse order but about the formatting of the template code in the snippet itself.

Comment: @arvinsim, Ah, indeed, too closely named. In that case, I must update my comment; Snippet Sync would be my vote.

Comment: Is there an EE3 solution for this? My understanding is that EE3 Partials have the same scope as EE2 Snippets, but that SnippetsSync is only compatible with EE2.

Comment: Just learned the answer to my previous question. EllisLab tell me that version control of Template Partials (Snippets) and Template Variables as files is possible under EE3. And I now see the answer was staring me in the face at https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/templates_as_files.html :)

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer [Low Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) as it does so much more than just let you edit as files. You can control the parse order allowing you to create global variables or snippets. Plus it works with a whole bunch of field types making it extremely useful for content that clients need to edit but don't deserve a channel. And yes you can hide variables/snippets from clients so your client only sees what they need to.